# scanf to fgets C

Tags: c, validation, scanf, fgets

Say I need to read in two name
like, `[name name]\n` .... (possibly
more `[name name]\n` . Assuming the name
can have length of 19, my code so far
is, How would I actually prevent an input like `[name name name]\n` or more `[name name name...]\n` in my case ? I heard about fgets() and fscanf but would anyone kindly show me an example how to use them? Thanks in advance.

```
char name1[20];
char name2[20];
for(int i=0; i < numberOfRow ; i++){
  scanf(" %s %s", name1, name2);
}
```

Ok So I found a way to make sure there is only two element, but I am not sure how to put them back into variable...

```
char str[50];
int i;
int count = 0;
fgets(str, 50, stdin);

i = strlen(str)-1;
for(int x=0; x < i ;x++){
  if(isspace(str[x]))
    count++;
}
if(counter > 1){
  printf("Error: More than 2 elements.\n");
}else if{
//How do i place those two element back into the variable ?
char name1[20];
char name2[20];
```

}

Comment: There is a possibility for undefined behaviour if the input strings are more than 20 characters. Use `%20s %20s` instead.

Comment: You need to account for the null terminator **NOT** being counted by the `width` specifier in `scanf` format string. An array with 20 characters should have a corresponding `"%19s"` (or `"%19["`) format string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use strtok (string.h). Please be careful, this function will modify your source string (you may copy the string before).

Example for strtok:

```
char* word;

// First word:
word = strtok(str, " "); // space as the delimiter
strncpy(name1, word, sizeof(name1) - 1); 
name1[sizeof(name1) - 1] = 0;  // end of word, in case the word size is > sizeof(name1)    

// Second word
word = strtok (NULL, " ");
strncpy(name2, word, sizeof(name2) - 1);
name2[sizeof(name2) - 1] = 0;
```

Also, I think you should chec

Answer (score 0):

If you are going from standard input, there is no way of stopping this, the user can enter what they like. It would be preferable to read in all the input first then check then result.

Comment: Could I read in the whole line, then check if there is only two name ?

Comment: Depends, basically you would need to examine the input to see what you have got. You could have all sorts of characters in that string, including numbers, special characters, etc. I would not recommend using sscanf on the input if that is what you mean.

Comment: So far i used fgets , got the whole line, and used isspace to determine if there is more than 1 whitespace ... is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can use fgets to read all the line, and then parse the results.
for example:

```
char name[256];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++)
{
   if (fgets(name, 256, stdin) != NULL)
   {
      // Parse string
   }
}
```

fgets reads the line, until Enter is pressed.
Now you need to parse this string, if user enter wrong input (as "aaa" or "aaa bbb ccc") return error, else ("aaa bbb"), split the string and use "aaa" as name1 and "bbb" as name2

Comment: what if we are provided with test cases file like , test00.in test00.out. In this case would fgets be suitable ?

Comment: Yes. also, pmg is right, you can use the console as the file. See example in wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fgets

Comment: `fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)` reads from the keyboard .. well, from `stdin` and `stdin` is, very often, the keyboard.